How to make login component default route instead of home component
//layout.js:
"use client";

import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import Header from "./layouts/Header/Index";
import Sidebar from "./layouts/Sidebar/Index";
import Footer from "./layouts/Footer/Index";
import { useState } from "react";

// const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

const metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const [isSidebarExpanded, setSidebarExpanded] = useState(false);

  const toggleSidebar = () => {
    setSidebarExpanded(!isSidebarExpanded);
    console.log(isSidebarExpanded);
  };
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <div className="flex flex-col">
          <Header onToggleSidebar={toggleSidebar} />
          <div className="flex flex-1">
            <Sidebar isExpanded={isSidebarExpanded} />
            <div className="flex-1  pt-24 px-12 pb-12 lg:px-12 relative overflow-y-auto max-h-screen">
              <div className="overflow-auto">{children}</div>
            </div>
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

//page.js
import Image from "next/image";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
  );
}

//(pages)/login/page.jsx:
"use client";
import React from "react";
import Input from "@/app/components/Input/Input";
import Button from "@/app/components/Button/Button";

const Login = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-end h-[100vh]">
        <h1 className="text-black text-center">
          Login with username and password.
        </h1>
        <div className="mt-4 ">
          <Input placeholder="Username" />
          <Input placeholder="password" />
          <div className="mt-4">
            <Button
              label="Login"
              style="Primary"
              customClassName="w-36 h-[40px]"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;

when the page loads. the default route will be the page.js which is my home page. what i want to accomplish is that the login component or page will be rendered first without the header,sidebar,and footer or the login page will be rendered first without being inside of the children in the layout.js. and when i accomplish the forms. i can now be redirected to the home page route or "/" route.
i dont know if this is the time that i need to use protected routes? Thank you

I would recommend keeping /login in a route group and also putting your homepage in one. Doing so will allow you to separate the layouts. I'd use middleware redirect users to the correct page.
Your folder structure would be
middleware.ts
app - folder
 layout.tsx - main layout file, minimal formatting, no headers, no footers, etc.  
 (auth) - route group folder
 (pages) - route group folder

app
 layout.tsx - main layout  
 (auth) - route group top level folder
   layout.tsx // layout file without header/footer, used just for all pages in (auth) group
   login - folder
    page.tsx // page file
  (pages) - route group top level folder
   layout.tsx // layout file with header/footer etc used for all pages in (pages) group
   page.tsx // your authenticated home page file

middleware.ts // adjust to your exact needs
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
 
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  // get your current user using your auth setup.
  const currentUser = request.cookies.get('currentUser')?.value
 
  // logged in don't allow to access login page
  if (currentUser && request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/login')) {
    return Response.redirect(new URL('/', request.url))
  }
  // not logged in redirect to login page
  if (!currentUser && !request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/login')) {
    return Response.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url))
  }
 // all other routes require auth 
}
 
export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|.*\\.png$).*)'],
}

root layout.tsx
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

(pages) > layout.tsx
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const [isSidebarExpanded, setSidebarExpanded] = useState(false);

  const toggleSidebar = () => {
    setSidebarExpanded(!isSidebarExpanded);
    console.log(isSidebarExpanded);
  };
  return (
        <div className="flex flex-col">
          <Header onToggleSidebar={toggleSidebar} />
          <div className="flex flex-1">
            <Sidebar isExpanded={isSidebarExpanded} />
            <div className="flex-1  pt-24 px-12 pb-12 lg:px-12 relative overflow-y-auto max-h-screen">
              <div className="overflow-auto">{children}</div>
            </div>
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </div>
  );
}

const metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

(auth) > layout.tsx // style however you need.
export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return <>{children}</>;
}

